# Why multi-region Kubernetes deployments are not recommended?

Tags: kubernetes

Kubernetes documentation is saying that multi-zone clusters are supported, but not the multi-region ones. At the same time Kubernetes has support for both `failure-domain/zone` and `failure-domain/region`.

What are the downsides of having my Kubernetes clusters to be multi-zone and multi-region at the same time? Is it only latency and if so what are the required latency numbers for it to be reliable?

On a plus side I see service discovery and being able to deploy applications across multiple regions without and extra tooling on top of it.

I know there's federation v1 and v2 being worked on but it seems to be adding a lot of complexity and v2 is far from being production ready.

Comment: I've found some that etcd can run across datacenter but requires some tuning - https://coreos.com/etcd/docs/latest/faq.html. Wonder what else should be taken into consideration.

Comment: etcd FAQ link in previous comment no longer works. https://etcd.io/docs/v3.5/faq/#does-etcd-work-in-cross-region-or-cross-data-center-deployments seems related.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is speculative, but it's *informed* speculation, so hopefully that means it'll still be helpful

Let's take two things that kubernetes does and extrapolate them into a multi-region cluster:

- load balancer membership -- at least on AWS, there is no mechanism for adding members of a different region to a load balancer, meaning `type: LoadBalancer` could not assign all `Pod`s to the `Service`
- persistent volume attachment -- similarly on AWS, there is no mechanism for attaching EBS volumes across even availability zones, to say nothing of across regions

For each of those, one will absolutely be able to find "yes, but!" scenarios to demonstrate a situation where these restrictions won't matter. However, since kubernetes is trying to solve for the general case, in a cloud-agnostic way, that's my strong suspicion why they would recommend against even trying a multi-region cluster -- regardless of whether it happens to work for your situation right now.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I don't have experience with Kubernetes on AWS. My current clusters are on bare metal and I'm investigating cross-datacenter(aka cross-region for AWS/GCP) clusters. I have custom load balancers and rook/ceph for storage.

Comment: Well, in that case you actually may be immune to all the concerns (and thus would probably fall into the "yes, but!" category :-) ). So long as you have an Ingress controller, or its equivalent, that is datacenter-aware, and have a similarly good story around persistent volume management, then I guess "try it" is the short version

Comment: Hi @Maklaus, did you end up getting it working? Do you mind sharing your experience if you do? Thanks!