# How can you connect an external server/vps to an Amazon's EKS Cluster as a worker node?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, devops

For example, imagine you buy a VPS from DigitalOcean and you have an Amazon EKS Cluster (Kubernetes Hosted on Amazon).

How can you add the DigitalOcean VPS to the Amazon EKS Cluster as a worker node so that pods get scheduled on it?

The reason I want to do something like this is that I have a VPS in a local cloud provider that I want to schedule a specific deployment on because of the fact that it is closer to the target audience geographically.

Amazon does not provide a server close to the target audience and I unfortunately cannot buy an amazon outpost service for that particular cloud provider.

Comment: I would highly recommend doing a separate cluster per region rather than try to have a single multi region cluster. AFAIK EKS instances must be ec2 instances.

Comment: @jordanm Why is that so?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52808393/1032785